# Emails pushed into pending in Google Apps Groups

Tags: google-workspace, email, google-groups

We currently have many Google Apps groups setup internally for local and sometimes external communications within the company. However, recently some groups are blocking certain members’ emails (pushing them to the “pending messages” queue).

Some users’ messages are always being pushed to the pending messages queue but we cannot work out why this is happening or how to solve it.

What do you advise please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Groups, for whatever reason, will see some messages as spam and place the message in a pending queue. Go into the Settings and under Moderation in the Spam Messages section click the drop menu and select Skip the moderation and post to the group.

Comment: Google Groups must have changed its user interface since this answer was originally posted. Here is how I did this: (1) Click "Group Settings" on the left, (2) click the "Advanced" slider in the upper-right, (3) change the "Spam message handling" setting to "Post suspicious messages to the group".